# I want to convert HEX color to RGB color with input type="color" in React.js

Tags: reactjs

What I want to achieve　is
I would like to convert the HEX format color to RGB color and make a POST request
with input type="color".

**Issue/error message**

The contents of hexToRGB() are always
[0, 0, 0]
and I can't change color.
When I move color picker, console.log(e.target.value) shows
like #944242 (example) in console so I'm sure

works
I don't know how to covert HEX color to RGB color with input type="color" in React.js

I refer the following link but nothing works...

https://codepen.io/urosurosevic/pen/pagxYE

```
const LightDetailCondo = () => {

  const [hex_value, setHexValue] = useState("#fffff");
  
  const hexToRGB = (hex_value) => {
     hex_value = '0x' + hex_value
     let r = hex_value >> 16 & 0xFF
     let g = hex_value >> 8 & 0xFF
     let b = hex_value & 0xFF
     return `[${r}, ${g}, ${b}]`
  }

  const handleSliderChange2 = (e) => {
    lightOn(e.target.value)
    setHexValue(e.target.value)
    console.log(e.target.value)
    
  }

  console.log(hexToRGB())


  const lightOn = async() => {
    console.log("Body sent to server", {
    rgb_color: hexToRGB(),
  })
    await axios.post('xxx.com',
      {
        rgb_color: hexToRGB(),
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('Color Changed!');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Missed Color Changed!');
      });
  }



    useEffect(() => {

      }, []);



  return (
    <div>
        <input type="color" name="favorite_color" onChange={handleSliderChange2}>
    </div>
    );
}
export default LightDetailCondo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hexToRGB` function expects an argument with the hex value. You call it without parameters so it is always undefined. You also use the same name for the parameter as the state variable, so inside the method you are actually shadowing the outer one.

You can

1. remove the parameter so that it uses the outer `hex_value`
2. pass the outer `hex_value` as a parameter to the method

Something like

```
const hexToRGB = () => {
  const numericValue = parseInt(hex_value, 16);
  const r = numericValue >> 16 & 0xFF;
  const g = numericValue >> 8 & 0xFF;
  const b = numericValue & 0xFF;
  return `[${r}, ${g}, ${b}]`
}
```

Comment: thanks but still always [0, 0, 0]

Comment: @lion-react right, that is because the `type="color"` returns the color with the starting `#`. So you need to remove that.  `const numericValue = parseInt(hex_value.slice(1), 16);`

Comment: @lion-react see updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/XWBEdbg?editors=0011)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
<script>
  let d = "#abd450".replace("#" ,"")
   let c2hex = `rgba(${Array.from(d).map((a , _) =>  _  % 2 == 0 ?  parseInt(d[_] + d[_ + 1] , 16) + "," : null ).join("")} 1)`
  console.log(c2hex)

   //2nd method =>
   const hex2rgb = hex => [...hex.match(/\w\w/g)].map(x => parseInt(x, 16));
   hex2rgb("#40abdc")

</script>
```